# C++: Cannot convert from foo& to foo*

Tags: c++, syntax, pointers

I have a method:

```
odp(foo& bar);
```

I'm trying to call it:

```
foo baz;
odp(&baz);
```

I get a compiler error:

```
error C2664: "odp" cannot convert parameter 1 from 'foo *' to 'foo &'
```

What am I doing wrong? Aren't I passing in a reference to `baz`?

**UPDATE**: Perhaps I have a misconception about the relationship between pointers and references. I thought that they were the same, except references couldn't be null. Is that incorrect?

Comment: No, you're passing a pointer to `baz`. The `&` operator takes the address of an object (giving you a pointer).

Comment: Pointers and references are not at all the same. They are both means of performing indirection, but there the similarities end. They are not by any means interchangeable.

Comment: Sounds like you might need a good book to teach you what everything means. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @GManNickG tyler is absolutely right, its you who need a good book...

Comment: @shobi: Huh? What are you talking about? Where did I say Tyler was wrong? My comment is obviously directed at Rosarch, that's why my comment doesn't start with `@Tyler`.

Comment: oopss sorry but i cant find rosarch here, apologize...

Comment: @shobi: He's the original poster. It's all good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you apply the unary `&` operator to an object, you get a *pointer* to that object, not a *reference*. You need a reference in this case. In order to initialize a reference parameter, you don't need to apply any operators at all: an lvalue object can immediately be used by itself to initialize a reference of the appropriate type.

The informal synonymity between the notions of "pointer" and "reference" (as in "pass by pointer" and "pass by reference") is specific to C language. But in C++ they mean two completely different things.

Comment: Could you elaborate further on the difference between pointers and references?

Comment: @Rosarch: They are two different things. Drop what you think you know about them, there's your difference. References are aliases to variables, pointers are addresses of variables, they are different. A reference can't be "null" because you can't alias a non-existent variable.

Comment: The critical point here is that, "references are _aliases_ to variables." They are not pointers to variables.

Answer (score 4):

The odp function need a reference to a foo var whereas you are passing the adress of a foo var (pointer).

Just pass `baz` like:

```
foo baz;
opd(baz);
```

And it will compile.

Comment: mm... I thought that doing what would actually copy `baz` onto the stack, so if I make changes to `baz`, they won't be seen by the caller?

Comment: Any changes to baz will be seen by the caller this way.

Comment: No you are passing the reference to the var so it will work as you want. ANy modification of baz into odp() will be seend after returning from odp().

Comment: `odp(foo& bar)` means that `bar` argument will be passed by reference.

Comment: The `&` character in the method signature changes it so that `opd` works on a reference to `baz`, not a copy. When the method is declared to take a reference, the argument is converted to a reference implicitly when you call it, removing the need to add `&`.

Answer (score 2):

No, you're passing a *pointer* to `baz`. Drop the `&`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use &baz, you are actually saying address of baz, so you are passing a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

References and pointers are NOT the same in C++ - although you have probably read that most compilers implement references using pointers at the machine-code level.  You don't need to care how they are implemented by the compiler - but what the semantics of a "reference" and a "pointer" are in C++.

```
int i = 5;
int &j = i;  // j refers to the variable i
// wherever the code uses j, it actually uses i
j++;  // I just changed i from 5 to 6
int *pj = &i;  // pj is a pointer to i
(*pj)--;  // I just changed i back to 5
```

Note that I can change pj to point to another integer, but I cannot change the reference j to refer to another integer.

```
int k = 10;
pj = &k;  // pj now actually points to k
(*pj)++;  // I just changed k to 11
j = k;  // no, this doesn't change the reference j to refer to k instead of i,
// but this statement just assigned k to i, that is, i now equals 11!
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++, references are *aliases,* not addresses. You can, for instance, have multiple names for a single pointer, just as you might have multiple names for a single real object.

When you declare a function taking a reference parameter, the function will automatically alias whatever variable you pass to it. Whatever it aliases, though, must be of the same type as the reference. In your case, you are aliasing an `int*` with an `int` reference, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're being misled by old C conventions? In C, you "pass by reference" by creating a pointer, because the language doesn't have references - you use the pointer to "reference" the original variable. In C++, references *are* supported by the language and there's no need to create a pointer to the variable when you call the function.

```
foo baz; 
odp(baz);
```